# SQL in Access 2003: INSERT INTO and multiple SELECT queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, ms-access-2003

I'm using Access 2003 (forced to do it due to retrocompatibility) to modify a 10 years old project, not made by me.
I encounter errors in executing this query:

```
INSERT INTO ClientiContratto ( ID, CLIENTE, DATA, PERIODO, IMPORTO, FATTURATO )
SELECT [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente] AS Espr1, (SELECT Nome from TAnagrafica WHERE TAnagrafica.IDAnagr = [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente]) AS Espr2, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Data] AS Espr3, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Periodo] AS Espr4, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Importo] AS Espr5, False AS Espr6;
```

That returns errors due to

```
 (SELECT Nome from TAnagrafica WHERE TAnagrafica.IDAnagr = [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente]) AS Espr2
```

If I execute this query standalone, it works like a charm but when it comes to inserting the query into the INSERT INTO...SELECT statement, it returns (translated from italian):

> Runtime error '3000': Reserved error (-3025): there are no messages
>   for this error.

The aim is to insert in a table some new values based on values found in the active form, and the part of code which isn't working should search into a table a value linked to the [InserisciContratto]![Cliente] actual value.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe is that because I cant execute a SELECT subquery in a previous SELECT query?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no such thing as _generic errors_. Be specific: which errors do you actually get?

Comment: That select command is probably returning more than one row as result. Either add top 1 to limit the result set or understand what this is about and re-write the SQL properly.

Comment: @krishKM how do i put a top 1 in that query?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth actually it seems a generic error , as it says (translated from italian): Runtime error '3000': Reserved error (-3025): there are no messages for this error. I'll edit my question to be more specific

Comment: `SELECT Top 1 Nome … rest of the sql`

Comment: @WyattGillette That's one of the least generic ones, since it's a _There's stuff happening that's so weird we didn't even consider making an error message for it_ error, which means it excludes most usual sources of problems. Anyway, try using a `DLookUp` instead of a subquery, that usually avoids this kind of stuff: `DLookUp("Nome", "TAnagrafica", "TAnagrafica.IDAnagr = [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente]")`. If it works, I can repost it as an answer.

Comment: I would recommend breaking up your problems in pieces. Make sure your INSERT statement can insert with test values. Then add in the form control references. This way you can diagnose the true problem area.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth actually it works like a charm. I used a workaround by the way, because obviously i couldn't insert DLookUp in the query, so I set a text box with DLookUp and I made the query read that textbox. 
If you post it as an answer, i will accept it.
Thanks!

Comment: @WyattGillette Posted as an answer. To make it a more full answer, I've provided some additional workarounds that commonly work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around the problem using a `DLookUp` instead of a subquery:

```
DLookUp("Nome", "TAnagrafica", "TAnagrafica.IDAnagr = [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente]")
```

Note that you can either use the `DLookUp` on a form control, or in a query. Both are valid. In the query, it'd look like this:

```
INSERT INTO ClientiContratto ( ID, CLIENTE, DATA, PERIODO, IMPORTO, FATTURATO )
SELECT [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente] AS Espr1, DLookUp("Nome", "TAnagrafica", "TAnagrafica.IDAnagr = [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente]") AS Espr2, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Data] AS Espr3, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Periodo] AS Espr4, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Importo] AS Espr5, False AS Espr6;
```

An alternate, common source of these kind of errors is that Access behaves finicky when using subqueries and not querying from a real table. You can easily work around that by using the subquery as the main query. Note that this does require the subquery to always return a result, else no row will be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO ClientiContratto ( ID, CLIENTE, DATA, PERIODO, IMPORTO, FATTURATO )
SELECT [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente] AS Espr1, Nome AS Espr2, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Data] AS Espr3, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Periodo] AS Espr4, [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Importo] AS Espr5, False AS Espr6
FROM TAnagrafica
WHERE TAnagrafica.IDAnagr = [Forms]![InserisciContratto]![Cliente]
```

Comment: Thank you, also for the clarifications!
I didn't even know that you can use DLookUp in a query, and the last method is also something I didn't realize! 
Very helpful